# How to achieve textured color gradients?

Tags: gimp, gradient, image-processing

Some examples are below (source: https://www.etsy.com/shop/JazzberryBlue). How do I achieve gradients like this in Gimp? Or if not Gimp, what is the general process for creating gradients that blend with this kind of "spray paint"/ink texture? Is there a name for it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Adobe Illustrator, this would be possible with a Gradient Mesh or Freeform Gradient with some Texturizer applied.

Comment: @Vincent - better with a raster image editor to be honest, and the OP is specifically asking about GIMP.  There's also a gradient mesh in Inkscape, but I wouldn't use it for this either.

Comment: @BillyKerr I knew of the GIMP pref, hence this being a comment and not an answer :). And yes, I agree that a raster editor would be better suited. Also to not have the size of the image file go Tunguska.

Answer (score 5):

IMHO a combination of a banded gradient with soft edges/transitions:

[image]

This gives this:

[image]

With a little bit of [Spread noise](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-filter-noise-spread.html) added:

[image]

The image you show is probably such a gradient applied  to a grayscale image using `Colors > Map > Gradient map`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is a gradient, at least not one that was created using the gradient tool. It's too irregular.

I would begin with something like this. These were just painted with a soft edged brush. You could make them more irregular than I did.

[image]

Then use the Warp Transform Tool, using the *Grow Area* setting to create something like this. To do this I set a large brush size (larger than the circle shown above), with about 95% hardness and quite a low strength setting. I then warped the image until it created a narrow black edge, then I reduced the brush size and hardness, and made some softer warping in the middle.

[image]

Then I used the HSV noise filter to add a texture

[image]

Here's [another example](https://imgur.com/Avb4p0Z), just messing around with more irregularities, and the different Warp tools.

Comment: Nice work Billy!